# android current location causes app crash

Tags: android, eclipse, api, dictionary

I created a concept app that grabs three locations and displays them on a google map: My school, my home and my current location.

The app used to work but now it crashes whenever I ask for it to pull the current location. I have made no changes to the app in the last week but now it will not function properly. Oddly, it will still pull up my school and home.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.location.Location;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;




//Loosely based on an App tutorial from Youtube by ram goud.

public class MapActivity extends Activity implements android.location.LocationListener {

    private final LatLng LOCATION_HOME = new LatLng(45.310488, -93.536989);
    private final LatLng LOCATION_SCHOOL = new LatLng(44.972586, -93.283689);
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected boolean gps_enabled, network_enabled;
    Button homeButton;
    Button schoolButton;
    Button currentLocation;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    private final LatLng LOCATION_CURRENT = null;

    private GoogleMap map;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);



        map =((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); 
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false); //I dislike this feature. That is why it has been removed. 

//      Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
//      String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, gps_enabled);
//      final Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


        homeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home_button);
        homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN); //MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN sets the map displayed as just a normal Google Map image.
                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_HOME, 14); // newLatLngZoom is for zooming. the # represents the distance. 21 furthest & 1 being closest.
                map.animateCamera(update);
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION_HOME).title("Hello, Home"));
            }

        });
        schoolButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.school_button);
        schoolButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE); //MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE sets the map displayed as a sat image
                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_SCHOOL, 16); // newLatLngZoom is for zooming. the # represents the distance. 21 furthest & 1 being closest.
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION_SCHOOL).title("Hello, School"));
                map.animateCamera(update);

            }
        });

        currentLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.current);
        currentLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GoToCurrent();

                }


        });


    }

    private void GoToCurrent() { //Method created to find current lat/long of user.
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, gps_enabled);
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        double lati = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double longi = myLocation.getLongitude();
         LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lati, longi);
         map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
         map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati, longi)).title("You are here"));
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




}
```

//This is the manifest, in case anyone is curious.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />



    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx" /> <!-- API key  -->
              <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>﻿
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you add the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the value of you myLocation variable is null or not before calling any methods on it

```
Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

if you look at the documentation , found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)

you will see that this function can return null

> public Location getLastKnownLocation (String provider) Added in API
>   level 1
>
> Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location
>   fix obtained from the given provider.
>
> This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this
>   location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned
>   off and moved to another location.
>
> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned. Parameters
>   provider  the name of the provider Returns
>
> ```
> the last known location for the provider, or **null**
> ```
>
> Throws SecurityException  if no suitable permission is present
>   IllegalArgumentException  if provider is null or doesn't exist

Answer (score -1):

So oddly enough, it's working no. No changes have been made to the code. It just... works!

Comment: The reason it works, is because getLastKnownLocation(provider) only returns null sometimes.  If you look at the doc, i posted above, you will see that, that method __can__ return null.  If you ignore that fact then at some point the app __will__ crash like it did before.  It's easy to just blow-off something that seems to have corrected it self, but if you are trying to learn something, then check for the null condition and show a toast, or print something to the log or anything if it is null and __don't__ call any methods on the null object.  Worst case you never see the toast/log message!